# Directories' permisions for automounted USB hard drive in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: usb, mount, ubuntu-9.10

I've noticed that directories' permissions for my automounted USB hard drive formatted in NTFS in Ubuntu 9.10 are 700. This is inconvenient for me. On Ubuntu 8.04 LTS it was 777 everywhere and it was good. Where can I change those default automount permissions for such a drive?

Answer (score 1):

you could be interested in [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/automount-permissions-for-external-usb-hhd-555022/) thread from linuxquestions.org.